# Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: rest, http, flutter, post, dart

I'm unable to find a solution. I'm getting the above exception when hitting http.post

This is Api provider class ==>

```
class SitesApiProvider {

  final _url = ApiStrings.GET_SITES_BY_COMPANY_ID_API;
 final _body= {
   "company_id" : 10
 };

  Future<SiteModel> fetchSitesList() async {
    print("inside sites list api");
    final response = await http.post(_url, body:_body);
    print("${response.body.toString()}");
    print("json body --- ${json.encode(body)}");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      return SiteModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {

      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
}
```

Is something i'm missing???

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. While mapping json value with the field of SiteModel doesn't have same data type. Add a debugger point and check where mapping fails in SiteModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the http package documentation  which you can find [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/http-library.html), The post method can have the followings as its body:

[image]

But you’re trying to pass a Map with String key and int value which is not possible and that’s why you’re getting the error. You can store the bales as a String and convert it to int when you receive it.

```
 final Map<String,String> _body= {
"company_id" : 10.toString() //your value is now String
};
```

And with this change, Your code must work.